# Combination of two methods are not working - Java

Tags: java

In this class I'm getting a string value from user. This has 2 functions.

- According to the word length of the input I want to assign points/marks(Ex: If the length of user input is 3 , I want to assign 3 points).
- Also each alphabetical letter has different point value.

  As the final output I want to show a  score combining  those two methods.
  Ex: (If user inputs 'APPLE' , final score should be= alphabetical points( 1+3+3+1+1) + wordlength points(9)
  Total = 9+9 = 18.

I have tried this ,but the final score is not generating. Please help me to fix this issue.

```
public void ScoreWord()
{
for(i=0; i < word.length();i++);
    {
wordchar = word.charAt(i-1);
lettervalue=0;
                
switch(wordchar)
{
        case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'L': case 'N': case 'O': case 'R':  case 'S': case 'T': case 'U':
        lettervalue= 1;
        break;
        
        case 'D': case 'G':
        lettervalue=2;
        break;
        
        case 'B': case 'C': case 'M': case 'P':
        lettervalue=3;
        break;
        
        case 'F': case 'H': case 'Y': case 'V': case 'W':
        lettervalue=4;
        break;
        
        case 'K':
        lettervalue=5;
        break;
        
        case 'J': case 'X':
        lettervalue=8;
        break;
        
        case 'Q': case 'Z':
        lettervalue=10;
        break;
}
                     
                                                
    if(words.length == 1)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[0];
    }
    if(words.length == 2)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[1];
    }
    if(words.length == 3)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[2];
    }
    if(words.length == 4)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[3];
    }
    if(words.length == 5)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[4];
    }
    if(words.length == 6)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[5];
    }
    if(words.length == 7)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[6];
    }
    if(words.length == 8)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[7];
    }
    if(words.length == 9)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[8];
    }
    if(words.length == 10)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[9];
    }
    if(words.length == 11)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[10];
    }
    if(words.length == 12)
    {
        scores= lettervalue+wordlength_score[11];
    }
                                                    
words[0]=word;                          
                
}
```

Comment: Please post a code example that shows the problem - not everything that's on your hard drive... :)

Comment: @code.hesh please post code that compiles - please excuse me but your example has some very basic java errors like a semicolon between the for loop and its body.

Comment: What are you going to do with the words with length over 12 ??? Your solution looks like https://github.com/AceLewis/my_first_calculator.py/blob/master/my_first_calculator.py

Comment: @tirpitz.verus- Very sorry I removed the semicolon . This is the error I'm getting now

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Comment: @code.hesh for `i = 0` `word.charAt(i-1)` => `word.charAt(-1)`

Comment: @code.hesh try for (i = 1; i <= word.length(); i++)

Comment: @SergeyRybalkin-same error

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you  have to create  a method that takes the string(word) as a parameter and returns the score based on the latters:

```
public int letterScore(String word)
{
    int lettervalue = 0;
    char wordchar;
    for(int i=0; i < word.length();i++)//what was this ; here?
    {
        wordchar = word.charAt(i);

        switch(wordchar)
        {
            case 'A': case 'E': case 'I': case 'L': case 'N': case 'O': case 'R':      case 'S': case 'T': case 'U':
            lettervalue+= 1;
            break;
            case 'D': case 'G':
            lettervalue+=2;
            break;
            case 'B': case 'C': case 'M': case 'P':
            lettervalue+=3;
            break;
            case 'F': case 'H': case 'Y': case 'V': case 'W':
            lettervalue+=4;
            break;
            case 'K':
            lettervalue+=5;
            break;
            case 'J': case 'X':
            lettervalue+=8;
            break;
            case 'Q': case 'Z':
            lettervalue+=10;
            break;        
       }



    }
    return lettervalue;
}
```

Now for example to can compute the score of a word like this:

```
String word = "APPLE";
int score = letterScore(word) + wordlength_score[word.length() - 1];//acording to you array the length must be [0,12] or else you will get an exception
```

EDIT:What you could also do is to create a method that computes the final score and return it, in that case you will have to do something like this:

```
int scorefinal(String word)
{
    int lettervalue = letterScore(word);//compute the letterscore
    return lettervalue + wordlength_score[word.length() - 1];//or return letterScore(word) + wordlength_score[word.length() - 1];
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Is this method correct.

    public int scorefinal(){
       
    int score = letterScore(word) + wordlength_score[word.length() - 1];
      return lettervalue + wordlength_score[word.length() - 1];
      
}

Comment: @code.hesh You want to create a method to return the final score?If so read the modification i suggest at the end of my answer.

Comment: @theVoid- Thank you so much. I did like this

    public int scorefinal(){
       
  
      return lettervalue + wordlength_score[word.length() - 1];
      
}

But in the output I'm getting null  0
(No errors. Other parts of the programme is working fine)